# cannot change the syntax of the controller creation in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have an angular controller wrote in typescript and declared this way

```
angular.module('myApp').controller("gestioneProgetto",     
 ["$scope", "PalmariService", "SoluzioniService", "ProgettoService", "WmsService", "BingService", "$modal", "SettoreService",  
  ($scope, dispositivi, soluzioni, progetti, wms, bing, modal, settore)     
=> new Palmare.Controllers.gestioneProgetto($scope, dispositivi, soluzioni, progetti, wms, bing, modal, settore)])
```

and is working fine. I want to change removing from here the di references, moving to

```
static $inject = ["$scope", "PalmariService", "SoluzioniService", "ProgettoService"
                 , "WmsService", "BingService", "$modal", "SettoreService"];
```

and changing to

```
angular.module('myApp').controller("gestioneProgetto", ($scope, dispositivi, soluzioni, progetti, wms, bing, modal, settore)
    => new Palmare.Controllers.gestioneProgetto($scope, dispositivi, soluzioni, progetti, wms, bing, modal, settore));
```

this approach worked fine with all the factoriesI changes, but trying with the first controller doing this I obtain the message

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dispositiviProvider <- dispositivi

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In case your definition is like this:

```
module Palmare.Controllers
{
    export class gestioneProgetto
    {
        static $inject = ["$scope", "PalmariService", "SoluzioniService", ...]; 
        ...
```

This should work for angular:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller("gestioneProgetto", Palmare.Controllers.gestioneProgetto);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Radim's correct answer, the reason this is happening is because Angular is looking for the `$inject` property on the object that is passed as the second argument to `controller`.

In this case, the argument you have here:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller("gestioneProgetto", ($scope, ... settore) => new Palmare.Controllers.gestioneProgetto($scope, ... settore));
```

is an anonymous function that doesn't have a `$inject` property. If you pass the controller constructor function itself, that constructor function *does* have the `$inject` property (because `static` members of a class appear as properties on the constructor function itself).